# rectangle size on template in itext confusing

Tags: java, templates, itext

I got a problem I do not really know how to proceed with... When I draw a rectangle on a page (the blue one in the picture) and then draw the same rectangle on a template on the same page (the green one), the rectangle on the template is larger. Has anybody a clue WHY?

Run the following class:

```
public class RectangleTemplate {

public static void main(String[] args){



    try {
        File file = new File("rectagnleTemplate_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".pdf");
        FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream(file);
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fileout);


        document.open();

        Rectangle rectangleOnPage = new Rectangle(20, 20, 100, 100);
        rectangleOnPage.setBorderColor(BaseColor.BLUE);
        rectangleOnPage.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
        rectangleOnPage.setBorderWidth(2);

        PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
        canvas.rectangle(rectangleOnPage);
        canvas.stroke();

        PdfTemplate template = canvas.createTemplate(document.getPageSize().getWidth(), document.getPageSize()
                .getHeight());

        template.rectangle(rectangleOnPage.getLeft(), rectangleOnPage.getBottom(), rectangleOnPage.getRight(),
                rectangleOnPage.getTop());

        template.setColorFill(BaseColor.GREEN
                             );

        template.fill();
        template.stroke();

        canvas.addTemplate(template, -10,-10);



        canvas.sanityCheck();
        canvas.stroke();




        document.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

the green rectangle should be as large as the blue one:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed confusing: iText 1, 2 and 5 grew organically: different people contributed code and as a result, there's a difference between the way a `Rectangle` object is created and the way you define a rectangle using the `rectangle()` method.

Take a look at the API docs:

The [Rectangle](http://developers.itextpdf.com/reference/com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle#3soc3nck64b) constructor looks like this:

```
public Rectangle(float llx, float lly, float urx, float ury)
```

You need the coordinates of the lower-left and the upper-right corner.

The [rectangle](http://developers.itextpdf.com/reference/com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte#bo2aj2np0ok) method looks like this:

```
 public void rectangle(float x, float y, float w, float h)
```

In this case, you only pass the coordinate of the lower-left corner. The other two parameters are the width and the height.

This line in your code is wrong:

```
template.rectangle(
    rectangleOnPage.getLeft(), rectangleOnPage.getBottom(),
    rectangleOnPage.getRight(), rectangleOnPage.getTop());
```

It should be:

```
template.rectangle(
    rectangleOnPage.getLeft(), rectangleOnPage.getBottom(),
    rectangleOnPage.getWidth(), rectangleOnPage.getHeight());
```

This problem is fixed in iText 7. iText 7 is a complete rewrite of iText by a coordinated team.